# Firebase Crashlytics For Xamarin iOS- Missing dSYM files

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

**Need Help !!**

We are getting caution message on top of the Dashboard in Firebase Crashlytics. We are tried with different technical advises in different forums.

But nothing has worked out for us. We are still seeing the caution message at the top (in red strip) and  crashes count is incrementing on every crash but doesn't come to Dashboard.

[image]

*Here we go with our Firebase Crashlytics integration with project :*

We are using Firebase Crashlytics with Xamarin Forms project to record any crashes in Mobile Application.

Since, Firebase Crashlytics SDK & Documentation are mostly on Native Platforms (Android & iOS). But, we still got provision to get packages from NuGet.

[image]

Here is the checklist which ensures we are on right direction:

**1)** Is App released with proper Apple Distribution Provision Profile and Certificate- **YES**

**2)** Is Distribution Provision Profile valid in terms expiration date - **YES**, it is valid till Next year from now.

**3)** Is GoogleService-Info.plist correctly placed. **YES**- it was downloaded from Crashlytics console with proper identifier configured. File was placed at root of iOS Project and set Build Action as *BundleResource*.

**4)** Did we call required initialisation function at proper place. - **YES**. Below set of codes ensures we initialised properly Firebase Crashlytics in AppDelegate.cs class.

[image]

**5)** Is your build configuration rightly placed in Release mode.  **YES**

[image]

**6)** **Important Point:** Firebase Crashlytics was able to process the reported crashes with earlier version of iOS build which were having same project and package configuration and we could able to see the Crashes in readable format till for immediate previous versions.

But suddenly it stopped working when we promoted to production in AppStore (**means LIVE in AppStore**)

**7)** Have we uploaded to dSYM file manually to Firebase Crashlytics - **YES** we **TRIED**. We followed the steps to upload dSYM using XCode-SWIFT project with POD files.

Here is the setup and step.

- POD was installed in appropriate XCode workspaces.

[image]

- Run Script was executed with recommended POD commands.

[image]

- Build was succeeded.

Hence, as you see, we are practiced with every advises whichever mentioned in any forum. We have applied, but we don't see, it is coming to Crashlytics Dashboard even then.

Answer (score 2):

Try below command. May be help full.

```
msbuild "/Users/xxx/projects/myApp/myApp/myApp.iOS/myApp.iOS.csproj" /t:"build" /p:Configuration="AppStore" /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:BuildIpa=true /p:FirebaseCrashlyticsUploadSymbolsEnabled=true
```

I have tried this command and it is working in my case. I get it from this git thread : https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/386

Comment: Thanks for quick response. We see, command  executes properly. And as expected, I could see the the terminal window shows with result  *"Successfully uploaded Crashlytics Symbols"*. But unfortunately, the red strip does not go away, and still incrementing further with forced App crashes. Any help on that!!

Comment: You have to upload dsym file that you get from your test flight build. To get that file first you have to allowed to submit that data when you upload build to testflight using xcode.